# Determining Minimum and Maximum Values During Particular Time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe similar to the below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ticker':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 
                             'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                   'date':['2020-05-01 09:30:00', '2020-05-01 09:31:00', '2020-05-01 09:32:00', '2020-05-01 09:33:00', '2020-05-01 09:34:00', 
                           '2020-05-01 09:30:00', '2020-05-01 09:31:00', '2020-05-01 09:32:00', '2020-05-01 09:33:00', '2020-05-01 09:34:00'], 
                   'datetime':['2020-05-01 09:30:00', '2020-05-01 09:31:00', '2020-05-01 09:32:00', '2020-05-01 09:33:00', '2020-05-01 09:34:00', 
                               '2020-05-01 09:30:00', '2020-05-01 09:31:00', '2020-05-01 09:32:00', '2020-05-01 09:33:00', '2020-05-01 09:34:00'], 
                   'low':[10.00, 11.00, 12.00, 11.00, 11.50,
                          15.00, 14.00, 13.00, 12.00, 12.50], 
                   'high':[10.25, 11.25, 12.25, 11.25, 11.75,
                          15.25, 14.25, 13.25, 12.25, 12.75], 
                   'close':[10.20, 11.20, 12.20, 11.20, 11.70,
                          15.20, 14.20, 13.20, 12.20, 12.75]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df = df.set_index(['ticker', 'date'])
```

I am trying to figure out how to create columns in my dataframe with the minimum and maximum prices of each ticker at a given point in time. That is, between the first time that day and the current time of the given row.

- For example, at 09:32:00, ticker B had a lowest price of 13.0 (occurring within that minute), but ticker A had a lowest price of 10.0 (which occurred at 09:30:00).
- Similarly, at 09:32:00, ticker B had a highest price of 11.25 (which occurred in that minute), but ticker A had a highest price of 15.25 (which occurred at the open at 09:30:00).

I've tried various different .groupby and .loc statements, but can't seem to get the right one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`.expanding()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) in combination with `.min()` and `.max()`, e.g.:

```py
df.groupby('ticker')[['low', 'high', 'close']].expanding().min()
```

```
                                    low   high  close
ticker ticker date                                   
A      A      2020-05-01 09:30:00  10.0  10.25   10.2
              2020-05-01 09:31:00  10.0  10.25   10.2
              2020-05-01 09:32:00  10.0  10.25   10.2
              2020-05-01 09:33:00  10.0  10.25   10.2
              2020-05-01 09:34:00  10.0  10.25   10.2
B      B      2020-05-01 09:30:00  15.0  15.25   15.2
              2020-05-01 09:31:00  14.0  14.25   14.2
              2020-05-01 09:32:00  13.0  13.25   13.2
              2020-05-01 09:33:00  12.0  12.25   12.2
              2020-05-01 09:34:00  12.0  12.25   12.2
```

It is basically like `.rolling()` but its length keeps increasing instead of the window being of fixed size.

Comment: This worked wonderfully! And I was able to just add a date column to the groupby statement to have it set on a daily basis as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you excally want, but I think the following code will work:

```
df[['date','low']].loc[df['ticker']=='A'].min()
```

Output:

```
date    2020-05-01 09:30:00
low                      10
```

You don't neet to set the index to the `ticker` and `date`